# Basemap layer is over the WMS layers

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have the problem that the WMS layers are hidden from the basemap, I try to solve the problem with the zIndex but it does not work. Any other ideas?

WMS Layer

```
var two = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Routen/wms', {
        layers: 'Routen:engelbecken',
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        format: 'image/png',
        zIndex: 1,
        transparent: true
        });
```

Basemap

```
var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 19,
zIndex: 2,
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
});
```

Comment: The stuff on top is the one with higher z-indexes - you should swap those, so that the WMS tilelayer has a higher z-index than the OSM basemap. Otherwise, see https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Comment: I try it also with a zIndex change but it does not work. I will try it with map-panes.